# Azure functions: is it possible to give multiple parameters to a queue trigger?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, serverless, powershell-core

I am very new to Azure Functions. I have a HTTP triggered function. From this http triggered function, I need to invoke a queue triggered function. **I was wondering when invoking queue trigger, can I pass more than one parameter?**

Below is my current `function.json` and run.ps1 of queue trigger

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "Jobname",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "JobQueue"
    }
  ]
}
```

`run.ps1`

```
param([string] $Jobname, $TriggerMetadata)
```

To invoke queue trigger inside HTTP triggered function, I am using below command

```
Push-OutputBinding -Name JobQueue -Value $value
```

Comment: The queue trigger only provides the queue message itself, along with the `$TriggerMetadata`. What additional information were you hoping to communicate? Perhaps it's already available to you...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen My use case demands 2 params to be passed to queue trigger such that status of job in queue can be queried later for knowing the progress. Is that something which cannot be done with queue trigger ? or something which queue trigger is not indented to be used for ?

Metadata of queue trigger only allows me to access values such as `$($TriggerMetadata.InsertionTime)` etc, right? can I pass another param via metadata?

Comment: You are not supposed to "invoke a queue triggered function" directly. You are supposed to put a message into a queue. Maybe have an output binding for your HttpTrigger function? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-powershell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1

From [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-powershell) found below code to send multiple messages at once from `run.ps1` file in HTTP trigger

```
$message = @("message1", "message2")
Push-OutputBinding -Name Msg -Value $message
```

But in above method, there was no reference for using the `Msg` variable at `run.ps1`of Queue trigger.

Method 2

Code in `run.ps1` and `function.json` files of HTTP Trigger

```
Push-OutputBinding -Name QueueItem1 -Value $message1
Push-OutputBinding -Name QueueItem2 -Value $message2
```

`function.json`

```
   {
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "QueueItem1",
      "connection": "<Storage>",
      "queueName": "egqueue"
    },
    {
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "QueueItem2",
      "connection": "<Storage>",
      "queueName": "egqueue"
    }
```

**Note:** *Both methods created separate entries with separate ID's in Storage Queue*